# How to detach from the Visual Tree in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visualtreehelper, inlineuicontainer

I'm trying to correctly remove a `UIElement` from an `InlineUIContainer` in order to use it in another Panel but the program keeps crashing with this message "Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.".

I've created a small application to illustrate my pain. In this program, once Randy the button is killed\deleted by his girlfriend, he doesn't still detach from his parent, whom I got find out was `UIElementIsland`. And then any attempt to add Randy as the child of anything else crashes the application (The Apocalypse Button proves my point :) ). You can click to check Randy's parents before\after deleting Randy to notice that he is constantly under `UIElementIsland` as a child, If he is detached the whole problem\apocalypse should be averted.

It's a Funny application so copy and compile even if it's just for the fun! Any help\ideas would be appreciated!

THE C# Part:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace DetachingfromUIElementIsland
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int t = 0;

        static string[] info = new string[] { "Okay, Lets have a look...", "Checking."
            , "Checking..", "Checking...", "Seen it!"  };

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes the App fancy :)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            display.Text = info[t];

            if (t == 0)
                timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300);

            t++;
            if (t >= 4)
            {
                t = 0;
                timer.Stop();
                display.Text = GetRandysParent();
            }
        }

        private void deleteRandy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // This might be the bug.
            // Maybe there's a better way to do this.
            // If there was a VisualTreeHelper.Remove().
            randy_container.Child = null;

            display.Text = "Haha! I just killed Randy!!! He'll never get the chance"
                + "\n to hurt another woman again!";
            display.Background = Brushes.Violet;
            end.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }

        DispatcherTimer timer = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if Randy is Still attached to UIElementIsland
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string GetRandysParent()
        {
            // Check the visual tree to see if randy is removed properly
            DependencyObject dp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(randy);
            string text = string.Empty;
            if (dp != null)
            {
                display.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                text = "Randy's Dad is Mr " + dp.ToString();
            }

            else
            {
                // This should be what you'll get when the code works properly
                display.Background = Brushes.Red;
                text = "Weird...Randy doesn't seem to have a dad...";
            }
            return text;
        }

        private void findParents_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {  
            display.Background = Brushes.Yellow;

            // Creates a timer to display some fancy stuff
            // and then Randy's.
            // Just to prove to you that this button actually works.
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Start();
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 700);
        }

        private void randy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get Randy to introduce himself
            display.Text = "Hi, I'm Randy!!!";
            display.Background = Brushes.Orange;
        }

        private void end_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // If randy is removed properly, this would not crash the application.
            StackPanel s = new StackPanel();
            s.Children.Add(randy);
            // CRASH!!!
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DetachingfromUIElementIsland.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <FlowDocument IsEnabled="True" x:Name="document">
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer x:Name="randy_container">
                <!--Meet Randy-->
                <Button Name="randy" Content="I am a Randy, the button" Click="randy_Click" ToolTip="Meet Randy"/>
            </InlineUIContainer>
            <LineBreak/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <InlineUIContainer x:Name="container2">
                <!--Meet Randy's Ex Girlfriend-->
            <Button Name="deleteRandy" Content="Randy dumped me for another girl :(, click me to delete him" Click="deleteRandy_Click" ToolTip="Meet Randy's Ex Girlfriend"/>
            </InlineUIContainer>
            <LineBreak/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <InlineUIContainer x:Name="container3">
                <!--He can help you find Randy's Parents-->
            <Button Name="findParents" Content="Click me to find randy's parents" Click="findParents_Click" ToolTip="He can help you find Randy's Parents"/>
            </InlineUIContainer>
            <LineBreak/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <InlineUIContainer x:Name="Apocalypse">
                <!--End the world, Crash the application-->
                <Button x:Name="end" Content="Avenge Randy's Death" Click="end_Click" ToolTip="End the world, Crash the application" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <TextBlock x:Name="display" Foreground="Black"/>  
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</Window>
```

The whole code was supposed to be shorter than this, but I spiced it up to make it a bit fun. Hope I brightened someone's day a little. But still, help me :).

**Answer:**
Derive from Randy's `InlineUIContainer` as follows:

```
    public class DerivedInlineUIContainer : InlineUIContainer
    {   
        public DerivedInlineUIContainer()
        {

        }

        public void RemoveFromLogicalTree(FrameworkElement f)
        {
            this.RemoveLogicalChild(f);
        }
    }
```

Now you could kill Randy properly this time, and add him to UIElement heaven (The `StackPanel`):

```
    randy_container.RemoveFromLogicalTree(randy);
    IDisposable disp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(randy) as IDisposable;
    if (disp != null)
        disp.Dispose();

    // Poor Randy is going to heaven...
    StackPanel heaven = new StackPanel();
    heaven.add(randy);
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: "spiced it up to make it a bit fun" is self-defeating here. Post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.

Comment: I think you also have to remove the InlineUiContainer from its parent (i.e. the Paragraph). I'm not sure why, but I have an extension method in my code that does exactly that because I had the same issues a couple of month ago.

Comment: Taken note of that. I'll make amends next time. Thank you @Clemens

Comment: Doesn't work. Just tried it @ Lennart

Comment: Note also that you may still edit your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the visual parent doesn't seem to help:

```
private void end_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IDisposable disp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(randy) as IDisposable;
    if (disp != null)
        disp.Dispose();

    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(randy);
    if (parent == null)
        MessageBox.Show("No parent");

    // If randy is removed properly, this would not crash the application.
    StackPanel s = new StackPanel();
    s.Children.Add(randy);
}
```

So you could either create a new `Button`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    randy_container.Child = CreateRandyButton();
}

private void end_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel s = new StackPanel();
    s.Children.Add(CreateRandyButton());
}

private Button CreateRandyButton()
{
    Button button = new Button { Name = "randy", Content = "I am a Randy, the button", ToolTip = "Meet Randy" };
    button.Click += randy_Click;
    return button;
}
```

...or simply hide it as suggested by @Sinatr.

Comment: Yes, it's still crashing, but the message has changed to "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.". I'll see how I can solve that

Comment: It should not crash when you do: s.Children.Add(CreateRandyButton());

Comment: Hey! Nice work!!! I derived from the `InlineUIContainer` and called `RemoveLogicalChild()`. Together with your  suggestion about `Dispose()`. And it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's funny, but also very noisy. You would get answer much faster if your demo is short.

Instead of removing/adding visual you can simply hide/show it:

```
void deleteRandy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
    randy.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

void end_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
    randy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

This way you are not playing with visual tree in unrecoverable way. You can use MVVM + data templates or `x:Shared=False` resources if you really want to remove UI element and then add **new one**.

Comment: Sounds great, but that's just a demo. I want to use the logic in a richtextbox.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround in case the parent is still a `UIElementIsland`. Since it implements `IDisposable`, you can clear its children that way:

```
var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
if (parent is IDisposable uiElementIsland)
{
   uiElementIsland.Dispose();
}
```

It's not nice, but it works.